# Collecting Web traffic and monitoring reports

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, firewall, internet, network-monitoring

My company is a med home health company and I have been tasked with seeing what people are doing on the internet. There's been a lot of people complaining of people shopping, surfing internet, etc on are term server and on employee computers.

We use 3 fire walls for different locations.

The firewall can tell me what ip address's use the most bandwidth and I also get a report telling me what websites were accessed behind the firewall. The only problem is both reports don't work with each other. What I mean is the web filtering report doesn't tell me what ip address is accessing the website. I am also having a problem with people jumping on are wireless using Pandora and other apps. Wireless is protected but all company phones, laptops , etc use are wireless.

can someone recommend some free software or ideas on what I can do to give me a report to show what websites certain ip address's are accessing. I`ve heard of setting up a proxy and using squid but I have no experience with them. My company is also cheap and will not buy expensive software.

Thanks
GA

Comment: It seems you are trying to solve a human resources problem with a technical solution.  I couldn't recommend more strongly against this.  It turns out that some slacking off throughout the workday is normal and healthy, and people feel spied upon when you do this.  That said, the way it's typically accomplished is by using a proxy, but the details are actually rather complicated.

Comment: Second the proxy solution.  This way you can block/allow specific websites in one area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetFlow and sFlow are frequently used for this sort of task. You didn't mention what kind of firewall you were running, but many of them will export one of those two things. There are a number of free collectors out there. [Cisco maintains a list of free tools](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/iosswrel/ps6537/ps6555/ps6601/networking_solutions_products_genericcontent0900aecd805ff72b.html), but I usually recommend [SiLK](http://tools.netsa.cert.org/silk/index.html), an open source tool developed by CERT. Be careful, as some of them are more intended for live monitoring and will only show you, say, the last 24 hours of traffic.

NetFlow won't (in general) give you the URL that was visited, only the IP address, but it's pretty easy to match up the major services like Pandora. (This is a plus, in my opinion, as it does help to preserve privacy)

I won't weigh in on the wisdom of tracking down who is connecting to what site, as that decision seems to be made above your pay grade.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no free version available. Commercial products you can try:

1. websense
2. wfilter enterprise
3. gfi web monitoring